# extract fundamental data from website

Tags: excel, extract

I am trying to extract fundamental data from website "http://www.cse.com.bd/companyDetails.php?scriptCode=ACI"
The information for excel will be written:
Stock Name  Total Securities    Market Capital  Authorized Capital  Paid-up Capital Reserve / Surplus   Director(%) Govt(%) Institue (%)    Foreign(%)  Public(%)   HY EPS
ACI 39,836,405  22,117.17   500 398.36  3442.32 34.79   0   31.42   0   33.79   60.28

How to make EXCEL MACRO for this? Advance thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a web query. This would be the simplest method.

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pull-data-into-microsoft-excel-with-web-queries/